# Compiling/Transpiling from Typescript to ES5 not working

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm using Webpack and try to use angular2.

That's why I edited all my things to be able to compile typescript. What I planned was to do it like [here](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/), so compiling typescript to ES6 and then transpiling it to ES5 with Babel.

This is, how my little App looks:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'angular-2-component',
    template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
})

export class angular2Component {
}
```

Then this is, how my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And that's the loader configuration in the webpack config:

```
{
   test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'
}
```

I also tried to play with the compilerOptions, to set target to es5, module to es2015, etc... But it's not working. I'm always getting the same error: `Unexpected token import`, pointing to the first line of the angular2Component-App. So it doesn't know import. Also, in Browser, you can see that only the @Component part seems to be compiled/transpiled correctly, then looking like this:

```
export let angular2Component = class angular2Component {};
    angular2Component = __decorate([Component({
        selector: 'angular-2-component',
        template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
    }), __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])], angular2Component);
```

But write above it, there's still the same line `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';`, which is not compiled/transpiled at all.

Does anybody have an idea, what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the author is't interested anymore, but could be of some help anyway.

Had the same problem for TS + Webpack + React.

Adding a simple **.babelrc** file, like

```
   {
     "presets": [
        ["latest", { "es2015": { "loose": true } }]
     ],
     "env": {},
     "comments": true
  }
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Did you reference this .babelrc file in your webpack config? or somewhere else?

Comment: @waz I don't remember doing that. Usually webpack finds `.babelrc` on its own. But it has been a while a go, can be wrong.